# Overridding Django Admin's object-tools bar for one Model

Tags: django, templates, overriding, admin

I am looking for the solution. I think a lot of different examples have confused me a little. I want to override the object-tools template in the Django admin.

I have one button on my model's tools:

[image: picture of django admin containing a button with the label "add customer"]

I need one other same type of button "Upload file". This should redirect me to the another view which I want to design myself in the same admin base template (with just one upload file control).

Answer (score 32):

[A]

Move `"django.contrib.admin"` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` to end of `INSTALLED_APPS`.

You can make template file

```
<your_app>/templates/admin/<your_app>/<your_model>/change_list.html
```

source code:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
  <li>
    <a href="<your-action-url>" class="addlink">
     Upload file
    </a>
  </li>
  {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

[B]

Add `change_list_template` into your ModelAdmin.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    change_list_template = '<path-to-my-template>.html'
```

And write template like [A] source code.

Comment: See related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45676500/django-admin-actions-on-single-object/45677862#45677862

Comment: You should mention `{{block.super}}` as well, It would be helpful for new users to get the [admin/change_form_object_tools.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form_object_tools.html) :-)

Answer (score 7):

It has become lot easier to accomplish what you're looking for since this question has been asked the first time.

The Django documentation has [a section on how to override admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates). To add a button to the changelist object tools, follow these steps:

1. Copy Django's version of the `change_list_object_tools.html` template file into your project's or app's template folder: `templates/admin/<app>/<model>/change_list_object_tools.html`.

   You can obtain the file form your virtual env's `site-packages` folder:

   ```sh
   cp $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list_tools.html templates/admin/$APP/$MODEL/
   ```

   Note that you might need to adjust the path to `site-packages` for your Python version.
2. Now open the template file. It will look liek this:

   ```html
   {% load i18n admin_urls %}

   {% block object-tools-items %}
     {% if has_add_permission %}
     <li>
       {% url cl.opts|admin_urlname:'add' as add_url %}
       <a href="{% add_preserved_filters add_url is_popup to_field %}" class="addlink">
         {% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name as name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}
       </a>
     </li>
     {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}
   ```
3. Add the link to your custom view:

   ```html
     …
     {% if has_add_permission %}
     <li><a class="addlink" href="{% url 'upload-file' %}">Upload file</a></li>
     <li>
     …
   ```

That's it! If you didn't know: you can add custom views and URLs to a ModelAdmin using `ModelAdmin.get_urls()` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls)). To not have to hardcode your custom admin URLs, you can of course reverse them ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls)).

Comment: What of `change` or update

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris Could you rephrase your question? I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use https://github.com/texastribune/django-object-actions. 
This will allow you to add buttons with custom logic. 
Though, I'm not sure whether you'll be able to a buttom for your list screen, as I did it only for a model-edit page.