# Django Admin Actions on single object

Tags: django, django-admin

The admin actions seem to work on several items selected in the list view of [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) admin interface:

In my case I would like to have a simple action button on the change (one item) view.

Is there a way to make the django admin actions available there?

I know that I can walk around this problem by going to the list view, and select one item there. But it would be more nice to have it directly available.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Create a template for your model in your app.

```
templates/admin/<yourapp>/<yourmodel>/change_form.html
```

With this example content to add a button when changing an existing object.

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {% if original %} {# Only show if changing #}
        <div class="submit-row">
            <a href="{% url 'custom-model-action' original.pk %}">
                 Another action
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Link that action to any url and redirect back to your model change object view. [More information about extending admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

**Update: Added complete common use case for custom action on existing object**

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^custom_model_action/(?P<object_pk>\d+)/$',
        core_views.custom_model_action, name='custom-model-action')
]
```

*views.py*

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

def custom_model_action(request, object_pk):
    messages.info(request, 'Performed custom action!')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(
       reverse('admin:<yourapp>_<yourmodel>_change', args=[object_pk])
    )
```

Comment: You missed `from django.urls import reverse`

Comment: Thank you! I have also learned how to show messages to the admin page using django.contrib.messages.

Comment: make sure to protect this endpoint!!

Answer (score 5):

If you realy need per-single object, I suggest you to use this solution, eg:

```
class Gallery(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='gallery/attachment/%Y/%m/%d')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def process_button(self):
        return ('<button id="%(id)s class="btn btn-default process_btn" '
                'data-value="%(value)s>Process</button>' % {'id': self.pk, 'value': self.attachment.url})
    process_button.short_description = 'Action'
    process_button.allow_tags = True
```

In your `admin.py`, insert `process_button` into  `list_display`;

```
class GalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'process_button', 'created']
    search_fields = ['title', 'pk']
    ....

    class Media:
        js = ('path/to/yourfile.js', )
```

Then, inside `yourfile.js`, you can also process it..

```
$('.process_btn').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');       // single object id
    var value = $(this).data('value'); // single object value
    ...
});
```

Hope it helpful..

Answer (score 2):

Not the same as the topic starter asked, but this snippet allows to have Single Object action from on the list page with **minimum amount of code**

**BaseAction code**

```
class AdminActionError(Exception):
    pass


class AdminObjectAction:
    """Base class for Django Admin actions for single object"""

    short_description = None
    exp_obj_state = {}

    def __init__(self, modeladmin, request, queryset):
        self.admin = modeladmin
        self.request = request
        self.queryset = queryset
        self.__call__()

    def validate_qs(self):
        count = self.queryset.count()
        if count != 1:
            self.error("You must select one object for this action.")

        if self.exp_obj_state:
            if self.queryset.filter(**self.exp_obj_state).count() != 1:
                self.error(f'Selected object does not meet the requirements: {self.exp_obj_state}')

    def error(self, msg):
        raise AdminActionError(msg)

    def get_object(self):
        return self.queryset.get()

    def process_object_action(self, obj):
        pass

    def validate_obj(self, obj):
        pass

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.validate_qs()
            obj = self.get_object()
            self.validate_obj(obj)
        except AdminActionError as e:
            self.admin.message_user(self.request, f"Failed: {e}", level=messages.ERROR)
        else:
            with transaction.atomic():
                result = self.process_object_action(obj)

            self.admin.message_user(self.request, f"Success: {self.short_description}, {result}")
```

**Custom Action [minimum amount of code]**

```
class RenewSubscriptionAction(AdminObjectAction):
    short_description = 'Renew subscription'

    exp_obj_state = {
        'child': None,
        'active_status': True,        
    }

    def process_object_action(self, obj):
        manager = RenewManager(user=obj.user, subscription=obj)
        return manager.process()
```

**AdminClass**

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [RenewSubscriptionAction]
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in admin actions operate on a queryset.

You can use a calable for the action you whant or to show something else:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display ('name' )
    readonly_fields('detail_url)


def detail_url(self, instance):
    url = reverse('product_detail', kwargs={'pk': instance.slug})
    response = format_html("""<a href="{0}">{0}</a>""", product_detail)
    return response
```

or using forms

```
class ProductForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.Charfield()

    def form_action(self, product, user):
        return Product.value(
            id=product.pk,
            user= user,
        .....

        )


@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

# render buttons and links to
def product_actions(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            '<a class="button" href="{}">Action1</a>&nbsp;'
            '<a class="button" href="{}">Action 2</a>',
            reverse('admin:product-action-1', args=[obj.pk]),
            reverse('admin:aproduct-action-3', args=[obj.pk]),
        )
```

[for more details about using forms](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-add-custom-action-buttons-to-django-admin-8d266f5b0d41)