# Add checkbox and delete actions to customized Django admin change_list

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've been customizing `Django`'s `change_list.html` following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-turn-django-admin-into-a-lightweight-dashboard-a0e0bbf609ad). My question concerns something that wasn't covered in that tutorial:

How to easily add the `checkbox` and the `actions` (delete selected items)?

I took a look in the `templatetags` of the admin section (mainly [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py), but I couldn't understand how to easily add the delete action to each item in a customized `change_list.html` template and what should be added to the `ModelAdmin` class).

**Update:**

Below is the custom `change_list.html`, I'm trying to add item checkboxes to:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}

{% block content_title %}
    <h1>Title</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block result_list %}
    <div class="results">
        <table id="result_list">
            <thead>
                ...
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                {% for item in items %}
                    <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
                        ...
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897291/django-writing-a-view-to-delete-an-item-with-checkboxes maybe duplicate

Comment: @MauricioCortazar Not really a duplicate, since for me I don't even know where to put the views when the admin section is overridden.

Comment: Sounds similiar with my previous [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45677306/6396981) or [this one](http://agusmakmun.github.io/python/django/2016/04/20/adding-broadcast-mail-to-all-users-registered-inside-django-admin.html).

Comment: @SancaKembang Thanks for the link. It seems similar to a solution I came across. Is it common to have a class method as a model field (like the `process_button()` in you solution)?

Comment: Can you post your template? The Tutorial is just an view not a form. Maybe there's a better way than to override the list block....in django.contrib.admin.options.changelist_view can you see all the "basic" magic.

Comment: @h4k1m nope. it custom. but Django can assign your function with `funcname.allow_tags = True` where you can use it eg for `list_display` in the admin, I think this would be useful if you need for each objects.. but, it will be deprecated in Django 2.0..

Comment: See this for more ["Support for the allow_tags attribute on ModelAdmin methods will be removed."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-2-0)

Comment: @SaschaRau I've just updated my question (you can see that the customized `chage_list.html` is very basic).

Comment: First of all, were you able to add checkboxes? Leave aside the linking between `delete selected` and the `checked` items.

Comment: @SwapnilMahajan I would just need to add `input type="checkbox" ` to the `html template` above. It's the management of the checked boxed that's a bit more complicated. Should I do that with `JQuery`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to look at the  "admin/change_list.html" template that is extended in "sale_summary_change_list.html". Its result_list block has the needed form. You will also have to add the input checkboxes to the returned query set in admin.py/changelist_view. I modified the code from the tutorial. We of course have to drop the aggregation on sales if we want to be able to delete individual items.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin, helpers

from .models import SaleSummary, Category


@admin.register(SaleSummary)
class SaleSummaryAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/sale_summary_change_list.html'
    date_hierarchy = 'date'

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        response = super(SaleSummaryAdmin, self).changelist_view(
            request,
            extra_context=extra_context,
        )
        try:
            qs = response.context_data['cl'].queryset
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            return response

        # metrics = {
        #     'total': Count('id'),
        #     'total_sales': Sum('amount'),
        # }
        result_qs = list(qs.values('category__name', 'pk', 'amount').order_by('category__name').all())
        map(lambda r: r.update(
            {'check_box': helpers.checkbox.render(helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME, r['pk'])}), result_qs)
        response.context_data['summary'] = list(result_qs)

        return response
```

And here is the template:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load humanize admin_list%}
{% block content_title %}
    <h1> Sales Summary </h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block result_list %}

          {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
          {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
    <div class="results">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div class="text">
                        <a href="#">Action</a>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="text">
                        <a href="#">Category</a>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="text">
                        <a href="#">Total Sales</a>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for row in summary %}
                <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
                    <td> {{ row.check_box }} </td>
                    <td> {{ row.category__name }} </td>
                    <td> {{ row.amount | intcomma }} </td>

                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block pagination %}{% endblock %}
```

Check the complete project on github:

https://github.com/SabirAkhadov/django-action-change-list-demo

Comment: Why did you use `force_text` when you injected the id as a value to the checkbox?

Comment: I guess it was a copy paste from somewhere, force_text is not actually needed here.

Comment: Which file did you copy from? I want to add links for each item in the `change_list.html` to the edit page. I know there is `ModelAdmin.list_display_links`, but I'm not sure if it would work in my case (with a customized admin).

Comment: there is an action_checkbox method in the ModelAdmin class which I could not figure out how to use directly so I copied its body.

Answer (score 1):

@Sabir Answer is the best one, and this one builds on top of it.

The part where he uses `map` to append the checkbox to the result list can give some performance issues when you are dealing with so many rows, let say 1000 rows

I found that : 
You can render the checkbox on the front end, and pass it the element pk.

You can keep the same admin class but remove the `map`  line in the change_list_view function and let the front end to the job.

So I changed my template like this

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load humanize admin_list%}
{% block content_title %}
    <h1> Sales Summary </h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block result_list %}

          {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
          {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
    <div class="results">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div class="text">
                        <a href="#">Action</a>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="text">
                        <a href="#">Category</a>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div class="text">
                        <a href="#">Total Sales</a>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for row in summary %}
                <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
                    <td> <td> <input type="checkbox" name="_selected_action" value={{row.pk}} class="action-select"> </td> </td>
                    <td> {{ row.category__name }} </td>
                    <td> {{ row.amount | intcomma }} </td>

                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block pagination %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Nice answer, still valid even with Django 3.0